# QTimer timout doesnt trigger in unit testing

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, qt5, qtimer

I'm trying to create a unit testing for a class i made named Counter. Such class should decrease its value "count" every 0.1 second, so I connected the method in the class constructor. Everything seems to work just fine in the original program, but when I try to run the unit tester it seems as the connection didnt happen or the QTimer doesnt send the timout signal at all.

gitHub link: https://github.com/allocro/TimerLFdP/tree/master/testCounter

```
Counter::Counter(QLineEdit *editSec, QLineEdit *editMin, QObject *parent) : 
QObject(parent)
{
    timer= new QTimer(this);
    [...]
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Counter::decCount);
}
```

EDIT: K, I'm gonna try to fit other code part in here as I'm being asked to do so.

In the precedend code, here is the constructor of the class I want to test, what decCount() doesis nothing else than that:

```
void Counter::decCount(){
    if (count>0)
        count--;
    else
        timer->stop();

    int countsec = count % 600;
    int countmin = (count - countsec)/600;

    QString secOut = QString::number(countsec/10) + "." 
    +QString::number(countsec%10);

    emit showCountMin(countmin);
    emit showCountSec(secOut);
}
```

The above signals are irrelevant to the unit tester code, they were used in the complete program.

Now, in the tst_testCounter.cpp, that as far as I understood, is the test unit version of the classic main, and I got

```
testCounter::testCounter() : QObject ()
{   int i;
    editSec= new QLineEdit();
    editMin= new QLineEdit();
    counter= new Counter(editSec, editMin);
    for(i=0; i<=10; i++){
        int randsec= rand() %60;
        int randmin= rand() %60;
        randsec=3;
        randmin=0; //To test the tester faster

        QString randsecString= QString::number(randsec);
        QString randminString= QString::number(randmin);


        editSec->setText(randsecString);
        editMin->setText(randminString);

        counter->set();//those are to input, they work fine, I checked
        std::cout << "Starting the Timer at " << (counter->count)/10 << 
        "sec" <<std::endl;
        counter->start(); //{timer->start();}

        while(counter->count>0){
            std::cout <<counter->count <<std::endl;
        }
        auto end= std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        counter->stop();

        auto check= std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - 
        start);
        int checkInt= check.count();

        if(checkInt==randsec+(randmin*60)){
            std::cout << "Timer matches" <<std::endl;
        }else{
        std::cout << "Timer doesnt match" <<std::endl;
        std::cout << "Sec counted: " << (counter->count)/10 <<std::endl;
        std::cout << "Sec passed: " << checkInt <<std::endl;
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

And obviously the .cpp ends in

```
QTEST_MAIN(testCounter)

#include "tst_testcounter.moc"
```

Comment: Do you have an event loop?

Comment: Please include **all** relevant code in your question - see [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - also, externally linked code is bad for multiple reasons.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, I thought the tester was considered as such itself. First time I use QT, sorry. I'm gonna look more into the event loops right now andupdate, but it is terribly confusing. Cant even find how do I star one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you should keep in mind is that `QTimer` is not exact, so doing a check in the order of seconds will cause problems, a better test verifies that the time difference in ms is less than a certain value.

On the other hand with the instruction:

```
while (counter-> count> 0) {
    std::cout << counter-> count << std::endl;
}
```

You are not letting the event loop work and therefore the QTimer or signals can work.

What you should use is `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`:

```
while(counter.count>0){
    QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents);
}
```

It is also recommended that the elements of the test be defined within the methods, and the test is not given in the constructor but in the slots.

Considering the above and giving other improvements, the following is obtained:

**counter.h**

```
#ifndef COUNTER_H
#define COUNTER_H

#include <QObject>
class QTimer;
class QLineEdit;

class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Counter(QLineEdit *setterSec, QLineEdit *setterMin, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QTimer *timer;
    QLineEdit *setterSec;
    QLineEdit *setterMin;
    int count;
signals:
    void showCountSec(const QString &count);
    void showCountMin(int count);

public slots:
    void decCount();
    void start();
    void stop();
    void set();
};

#endif // COUNTER_H
```

**counter.cpp**

```
#include "counter.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QIntValidator>
#include <QLineEdit>

Counter::Counter(QLineEdit *editSec, QLineEdit *editMin, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    timer(new QTimer(this)),
    setterSec(editSec),
    setterMin(editMin),
    count(0)
{
    setterSec->setValidator(new QIntValidator(0, 59, this));
    setterMin->setValidator(new QIntValidator(0, 59, this));
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Counter::decCount);
}

void Counter::start(){
    timer->start(100);
}

void Counter::stop(){
    timer->stop();
}

void Counter::set(){
    timer->stop();
    count = setterSec->text().toInt()*10 + setterMin->text().toInt()*600;
    int countsec = count % 600;
    int countmin = (count - countsec)/600;

    QString secOut = QString::number(countsec/10) + "." +QString::number(countsec%10);

    emit showCountMin(countmin);
    emit showCountSec(secOut);
}

void Counter::decCount(){
    if (count > 0)
            count--;
    else
        timer->stop();

    int countsec = count % 600;
    int countmin = (count - countsec)/600;

    QString secOut = QString::number(countsec/10) + "." +QString::number(countsec%10);

    emit showCountMin(countmin);
    emit showCountSec(secOut);
}
```

**tst_counter.h**

```
#include <QtTest>
#include "counter.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <QDebug>

// add necessary includes here

class tst_Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    tst_Counter();
    ~tst_Counter();

private slots:
    void initTestCD();
};

tst_Counter::tst_Counter() : QObject ()
{
}
tst_Counter::~tst_Counter()
{

}

void tst_Counter::initTestCD(){
    QLineEdit editSec;
    QLineEdit editMin;
    Counter counter(&editSec, &editMin);
    const int epsilon = 50; // ms

    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
        int randsec= rand() %60;
        int randmin= rand() %60;
        randsec =3;
        randmin =0; //To test the tester faster

        QString randsecString= QString::number(randsec);
        QString randminString= QString::number(randmin);


        editSec.setText(randsecString);
        editMin.setText(randminString);

        counter.set();//those are to input, they work fine, I checked
        qDebug() << "Starting the Timer at " << (counter.count)/10;

        auto start= std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        counter.start(); //{timer->start();}
        while(counter.count>0){
            QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents);
        }
        auto end= std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        counter.stop();
        auto check_ms= std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
        int checkInt = check_ms.count();
        int delta_s = randsec + randmin*60;
        int delta = std::abs(checkInt - delta_s);
        QVERIFY(delta < epsilon);

        qDebug() << "Sec counted: " << counter.count/10;
        qDebug() << "msec passed: " << checkInt;
    }
}

QTEST_MAIN(tst_Counter)

#include "tst_counter.moc"
```

output:

```
********* Start testing of tst_Counter *********
Config: Using QtTest library 5.11.2, Qt 5.11.2 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by GCC 8.2.1 20180831)
PASS   : tst_Counter::initTestCase()
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Starting the Timer at  3
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Sec counted:  0
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() msec passed:  3033
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Starting the Timer at  3
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Sec counted:  0
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() msec passed:  2999
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Starting the Timer at  3
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Sec counted:  0
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() msec passed:  3000
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Starting the Timer at  3
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Sec counted:  0
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() msec passed:  2999
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Starting the Timer at  3
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Sec counted:  0
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() msec passed:  2999
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Starting the Timer at  3
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Sec counted:  0
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() msec passed:  3000
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Starting the Timer at  3
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Sec counted:  0
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() msec passed:  2999
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Starting the Timer at  3
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Sec counted:  0
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() msec passed:  2999
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Starting the Timer at  3
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Sec counted:  0
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() msec passed:  2999
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Starting the Timer at  3
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Sec counted:  0
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() msec passed:  2999
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Starting the Timer at  3
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() Sec counted:  0
QDEBUG : tst_Counter::initTestCD() msec passed:  2999
PASS   : tst_Counter::initTestCD()
PASS   : tst_Counter::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 3 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted, 33078ms
********* Finished testing of tst_Counter *********
```

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/52442271-testCounter) you can find the complete example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up fixing it myself using QThread and other convoluted stuff, but yours is surely a better solution.